# Modifying innerHTML from 3rd Party Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have  a 3rd party script that is importing a menu and I cannot edit this 3rd party script. It generates code like this:

```
<div id="wmenu-updated" style="display: block;">
  <small>Menu updated</small>
  <span innerhtml="19 hours ago"></span>
</div>
```

It should take `19 hours ago` and display that as text inside the span but for whatever reason it doesn't work and the makers of the script are little help in fixing the error.

Is there a way, using jQuery, that once the page loads I can take the `innerhtml` and spit it out as text inside that span?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( '#wmenu-updated span' ).text( function () {
        return $( this ).attr( 'innerhtml' );
    });
});
```

You can use jQuery's [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to update the text in the span

Comment: That did it! Thank You!  I did have to change the `$( document ).ready` to `$(window).load` because the 3rd party script wasn't loaded before the other script ran.

Comment: @bobthecow's answer using span[innerhtml] looks better

Comment: @Christophe Why would you say that? His combination of selectors and find will execute slower. Not to mention an id of `#wmenu-updated` was provide, so I'm assuming that this will be the only case.

Comment: An interesting "behavior" of selectors is that they are evaluated right to left, so the id might not help much. $('#wmenu-updated').find('span') should work better. Also I agree that [innerhtml] doesn't add much value in the OP's example, but I am assuming that it is has been simplified for the forum (as the OP says, "code like this").

Comment: What you are talking about is CSS behavior, not Sizzles behavior.

Comment: -1 I'll be happy to convert it to an upvote if you prove your point (as I'll have learnt something), but in my book your last comment just confirms that this is the wrong answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678702/how-is-the-jquery-selector-foo-a-evaluated

Answer (score 6):

Use [$.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to achieve this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var txt = $("#wmenu-updated span").attr("innerhtml");
   $("#wmenu-updated span").text(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n76f9/)

```
 $(function(){
    $(document).children('#wmenu-updated').find('span[innerhtml]')
    .text($(this).attr("innerhtml"));
 });
```

or more simple like this:

```
$('span[innerhtml]').text($('span[innerhtml]').attr('innerhtml'));
```

Comment: Side note: That's not what `<kbd>` is for, although it may look spiffy.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function ( e ) {
    var q = $('span').attr('innerhtml');
    $('#wmenu-updated').children('span').text( q );
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Lots of people are getting it close :)

This will do it for you:

```
$('selector').find('span[innerhtml]').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).attr('innerhtml'));
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mWTaa/).

And this is functionally equivalent:

```
$('selector').find('span[innerhtml]').html(function() {
    return $(this).attr('innerhtml');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#wmenu span").attr("innerhtml", "Your Update here");
```

Comment: This only updates the attribute, but does not spew it out as the text of the span.

Comment: then do this: $("#wmenu span").text("Your Update here");

Comment: Please update your answer to reflect this. However, the OP's question is about updating the test with the attribute value. And not updating either with a new value.

Comment: And if you have several spans, you may also be more specific like $("#wmenu span:first").text("Your Update here");