# Why does Sizzle evaluate selectors from right to left?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, sizzle

Why does Sizzle evaluate selectors from right to left? Can anybody give me examples to explain why it will be faster when the selectors are evaluated from right to left than from left to right?

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left/5813672#5813672) mentioned, browser is different from the usual jQuery thing. If it isn't a matter of being faster, does it only follow how selectors works in browser, although it is not a good choice for selecting a collection of elements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678702/how-is-the-jquery-selector-foo-a-evaluated, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery--net-18052, http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html, http://davidwalsh.name/selectors

Answer (score 2):

It's not a matter of right-to-left being "faster", but rather [because that's how CSS selectors work](http://davidwalsh.name/selectors)

Comment: @Light I'm not sure what you mean: "Why does a CSS selector follow how CSS selectors work?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "being how CSS selectors work".

Comment: As [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/why-do-browsers-match-css-selectors-from-right-to-left/5813672#5813672) mentioned, browser is different from the usual jQuery thing. So do you mean that it only follows how selectors works in browser, although it is not a good choice for selecting a collection of elements?

Comment: I did read **all** of the links but I all I found are that Sizzle does evaluate selectors from right to left and how Sizzle evaluates selectors, not why Sizzle behaves same way as CSS selectors to select elements. I'm afraid I missed the reason. Would you mind pointing it out, please?

Comment: @Light: Your question is something only John Resig or someone from jQuery Core could answer. The linked question - about CSS selectors - was answered by a Firefox dev, which is as authoritative as it gets.