# Are references by ID, class name, or tag name most efficient in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When referencing elements in jQuery, which of the following is most efficient:

HTML:

```
<div id="divId" class="divClass">Div</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var div = $('div');
var div = $('#divId');
var div = $('.divClass');
```

Also considering compound references:

HTML:

```
<main id="mainId" class="mainClass">
    <div id="divId" class="divClass">Div</div>
</main>
```

jQuery:

```
var mainDiv = $('main div');
var mainDiv = $('#mainId #divId');
var mainDiv = $('.mainClass .divClass');
```

Comment: in jquery: `$(document.getElementById('divId'));`

Comment: [http://jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/jquery-simplest-selector-efficiency)

Comment: I don't know the correct answer, but you could use the [profiles tool](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles) in the chrome developer tools to see what takes the shortest time/least cpu.

Comment: Using pure javascript is the fastest. If you want to use JQuery, as you are in your example, it does not matter if you select something using the ID or Class. Either way is searching the DOM for that tag.

Comment: It also depends on the browser. If the browser does not have a native selector implementation, or is missing `getElementsByTag`, etc. those will be "slower." `getElementById` has always been native, and should perform the best of all. It really depends on if the DOM engine has a cache or not, and what is cached during document parsing/rendering.

Comment: Question already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393928/jquery-class-selector-vs-id-selector

Comment: Since `id`s are by definition unique, `$('#mainId #divId');` is redundant.

Comment: @steveax Sometimes it's useful to use nested ID selectors, if you want to test whether the descendant element has been moved out of a container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `id`s with `var mainDiv = $('#mainId #divId');` will perform best.

See the results of this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-get-elements)

If your targeting the inner `div` just use the straight `id` selector `$("#divId")` which is way faster: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-get-elements).  Using two `id`s in the selector actually slows things down.

Comment: jQuery will also use native `document.getElementsByClassName` If the browser supports it.

Comment: @steveax And the `id` will outperform the `class`: http://jsperf.com/anothertest

Comment: Indeed it will, but not because it's native, but rather that it's searching for a single element rather than (possibly) many elements.

Comment: @steveax I think the best solution is not listed, `$("#divId")`, which you have already mentioned.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: for the `$('#mainId #divId')` example, jQuery will use `.querySelectorAll`, or the Sizzle engine if `qSA` isn't available. It'll only use `getElementById` for simple selectors like `#foo`.

Answer (score 3):

It also depends on the browser. If the browser does not have a native selector implementation, or is missing `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName`, etc. those will be "slower." `getElementById` has always been native (as far back as I can remember), and should perform the best of all. It really depends on if the DOM engine has a cache or not, and what is cached during document parsing/rendering.

Remember, [jQuery uses Sizzle under the hood](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/), so this isn't really a question about jQuery, but [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/).

Sizzle attempts to use native DOM traversing methods, like `matchSelector`, where possible. In some cases where a shiv is needed (like a `:not(:has(span:eq(6))))`) non-native DOM traversal is required.

You should consider the complexity of the selector query, and from what part of the DOM tree the selector starts. Limiting your query is always faster than always starting from the root of the DOM: e.g. `$('#main').find('.someClass')` <strike>or `$('#main .someClass')`</strike>¹ as opposed to `$('.someClass')`.

*Perhaps this question is too open-ended.*

¹ <sup><sub>[Per @nick-f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250433/are-references-by-id-class-name-or-tag-name-most-efficient-in-jquery/20250594#comment47179521_20250594), "Sizzle processes the selectors from right to left" so `$('#main .someClass')` is not synonymous with `$('#main').find('.someClass')`.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, very interesting stuff. Your point about Sizzle under the hood is well taken. Surprised about the downvotes on the question, but I think you're right... too open-ended.

Comment: @StuartKershaw yw, and yea, I'm surprised they didn't close it as off-topic/too broad, and still haven't! your question is valid in my opinion, i generally disagree with closing types of questions like yours since *they are helpful*, they just generate really bad answers. where else are you going to put it other than SO? IRC? a forum? bah!

Comment: For what it's worth, `$('#main').find('.someClass')` and `$('#main .someClass')` are actually not the same. The former will limit your query as you suggest (find the element by id, then search within it), but the latter will actually find all `.someClass` elements first, then filter by parent elements. This is because Sizzle processes the selectors from right to left.